# Bash script - Trying get abuse email using whois command

Tags: linux, bash

How can I get only e-mail address from output?

```
 $ whois $IP | grep @ | head -1
 notify: albert@xxx.sig.xxx.tw
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the current output for the above command?

Comment: whois 203.xxx.xxx.105 | grep @ | head -1
notify:         albert@xxx.sig.xxx.tw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$ whois 203.xxx.xxx.105 | grep @ | head -1 | cut -d" " -f2
albert@xxx.sig.xxx.tw
```

This one will work as well:

```
$ whois 203.xxx.xxx.105 | grep @ | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
albert@xxx.sig.xxx.tw
```